# Make Visual Studio to show All Compile Errors!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

Visual studio does not show all the compile errors at once.
for example one time it says I have two errors and when I fix them then 102 more compile errors are showing up and these new errors are not dependent on those two previous errors.
How can we tell it to go through all the code and show all compile errors at once

Comment: I am using C# in VS 2008 Professional edition
..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is impossible to answer without knowing what compiler you use.  But in general you can't expect the full list of errors to be useful, one bad declaration can generate a slew of other errors in code that isn't actually wrong.  You can only really trust the first few errors.

Chip away at it, one error at a time, starting from the top of the list.  And make sure that your changes don't in turn generate a whole bunch of new errors.  Which is what is going on by the sound of it.

Comment: "Your sc is in rather poor shape" is not an answer for question.

Comment: This answer is not only useless, but deliberately insulting for no reason. The OP already mentioned that the subsequently revealed errors WERE NOT dependent on the ones fixed, so making that assumption is just plain insulting to the OP.

I've encountered the same issue, where the output panel says like "300 errors" but the error list only shows like 20 or something. It can be especially annoying when it only displays the errors that I wish to handle LAST, but because it's displaying them, it WON'T display any of the other errors that I would like to fix FIRST.

Answer (score 10):

For Visual Studio 2015, there is a setting for C# and Basic, Tools->Options->Text Editor->Lang->Advanced: Enable full solution analysis.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709421.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This is the correct answer. It will show all errors in visual studio and not limit the errors to open files. This is incredibly useful. Thanks for answering this!

Comment: Why this is not the accepted answer? TY @jmoreno

Comment: @StephanAhlf look at the timeline

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what language you're using [1] but there is no hidden setting that hides errors per-se, other than the compiler giving up after it has encountered an excessive number of issues (at least for Visual C++ [2]).

The trouble with (Visual) C++ [2] is that simple mistakes like missing braces and parenthesis, or unmatched `#include` guards, etc. causes a cascading set of failures that can be overwhelming causing a torrent of errors that means your tiny mistake is like the proverbial needle in a haystack. Hence the compiler can decide that it's best for both of you if it just stops early rather than fill your console or disk with error messages.

---

[1] They hadn't at the time I answered the question.

[2] back in 2010 when the question was asked.

**Update:** *while this answer is probably totally irrelevant 10 years later I'm leaving it in place for historical reasons. I have edited it to hopefully better show my original intent, which was to suggest that the **tool**, not the programmer is at fault. I apologise if the sarcasm in my answer was misinterpreted and any offence was caused.*

Answer (score 1):

Update of jmoreno's answer, **for versions of Visual Studio >= 16.5 (2019)** the "Enable full solution analysis" checkbox has gone, replaced by a set of radio buttons, at Text Editor/lang/Advanced

[image]

The equivalent is now "Entire Solution"

[More info - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/configure-live-code-analysis-scope-managed-code?view=vs-2019#custom-analysis-scope)

Answer (score -3):

The only reason it shows more errors is because the compile errors you just fixed caused them to happen. They weren't an issue earlier. May be you added a new reference or deleted some reference to fix one problem. One or both of those actions caused the 100 or more next compile errors to show up.

This is usually caused by poor design at a solution level, where there are too many cyclic or unnecessary references added causing ambiguity issues or similar type mismatch problems. This is of course just one of the many reasons.