# Visual Studio 2022 not showing compile time errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am new to Visual Studio and I can't seem to make it catch compile-time errors.

As can be seen, it does catch the style errors like extra spaces.

I have seen the post [Visual Studio not displaying compile time errors in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094125/visual-studio-not-displaying-compile-time-errors-in-editor), more specifically,

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454289/2525417
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40338353/2525417

But they don't seem to work. Other solutions are for older versions of Visual Studio.

However, when I build the project it does show the errors in the window at the bottom (output window)

[image: some errors caught some not]

Comment: Do you have the window Error List visible ?

If not, you can find it under menu View or use shortcut `Ctrl + W, E`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999983/make-visual-studio-to-show-all-compile-errors) can help you?

Comment: @Adrien the ultimate paragraph would seem to imply that it is visible

Comment: @caiusjard not really as he specify it's the Output Window, which will show build log and so build errors

Answer (score 6):

We had encountered same trouble when started to use VS 2022. Seems that there new option under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# and Visual Basic -> Advanced
Second option (in 17.4.1, that's the case) , with label 'Show compiler errors and warnings' , change to 'Entire Solution' from 'Open Document'

Beat me up, why default choice is put to Open Document. Scares a lot of peoples on that since after compilation, no errors in errors window.
Yes it is more performing, but why ?

Another similar post - [Make Visual Studio to show all compile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999983/make-visual-studio-to-show-all-compile-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1) but that one speaks on Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I had realized that option that i mentioned appeared in Visual Studio 2022 starting 17.3. Before there were only option to analyse solution/open document/nothing ...